# How are the groups $U_n$ constructed?

Tags: abstract-algebra

How are the groups $U_n=\{a \in\mathbb  Z_n \mid \gcd(a,n)=1 \}$ constructed?

Do they start with e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_5=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and then try multiplying through every element to a power $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (and between different elements?) and then taking $\mod 5$?
When does this end?

Comment: They are exactly those elements (minus the 5 in your example).

Answer (score 1):

Prove 1. That every element of $z \in U_n$ is such that $\gcd(z,n) = 1$.

2. That if $\gcd(z,n) = 1$, then $z \in U_n$ then it has an inverse $\mod n$.

This can probably be done in one fell swoop:

$zy = 1 \pmod n \iff zy - 1 = kn$ in $\Bbb{Z} \iff \exists y,k \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $zy + kn = 1 \iff \gcd(z, n) = 1$.

An abstract way of constructing them is to take the multiplicative group of units of the ring $\Bbb{Z}/(n),$ sometimes written $\Bbb{Z}/(n)^{\times}$.

See this nice [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) for more data.

It says for $n = p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$ (prime power decomposition of $n$), $\Bbb{Z}/(n)^{\times} \approx \Bbb{Z}/(p_1^{e_1}) \times \dots \times \Bbb{Z}/(p_k^{e_k})$.

Also the article gives isomorphisms to even simpler-appearing groups in cycle decomposition.

In group theory, an isomorphic group is just as good, or sometimes even easier, to work with.